# Facebook post not sending FBConnect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, facebook, fbconnect

I am using FBConnect for iPhone to post on the wall of the user in my iPhone Application.

Unfortunately for some reason this is not working with the dialog attachment I am using below.

```
dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"Check out %@.\",\"href\":\"%@\",\"description\":\"I found this! \",\"href\":\"%@\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"%@\",\"href\":\"%@\"}]}", song, songlink,songlink, link, link];
```

I would really appreciate it if you could tell me why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more attempts of fixing this, I found out that the FBConnect API does not support redirection URL's.

Thanks to @Myles Gray for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Dump your attachment to NSLog and verify that it's syntactically correct - does it say what you think it will?  Are all of your quotes balanced correctly?

Comment: I couldn't say whether all of the quotes are balanced correctly, but I can verify from the NSLog that it does say what I was expecting it to say.

Comment: After numerous attempts to get this fixed, I have found that the problem is with the href URL i am trying to provide inside the attachment. 

Everything else in the attachment works apart from that.

Any ideas why?